# How to set Intent result in Layout

Tags: android

friend's,
  I there any possibility to bind the result of Intent class in xml layout,

i'm doing it so for sending mail,i'm using below code for sending mail in

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] { "info@blacksheep.com" });
                sendIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
```

when i use the above code it opens a new page,but i need it to be in the layout alone.
How can i get it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i use the above code it opens a new page,but i need it to be in the layout alone. How can i get it.

You cannot do that, sorry. You are opening an activity from another application (whatever the user chooses to handle your `ACTION_SEND` request) -- it controls the presentation, not you.

Comment: @ hi CommonsWare,i need your help on implementing listview with footer,where i got the view as well with footer at bottom,here the problem is where the footer hava click event to parse next page url data to bind on  list view,where parsing to be good,but the list being stay back with previous page content,where the newly parsed data is not being added with list view,what is the problem,how can i fix it.just refer my question i posted with layout,i hope you may help me to get what i needed.

thanks in advance.